# from RTZ to GTFS format and vice versa

Tags: openstreetmap, general-transit-feed-specification

I'm using Open Street Map (OSM) and Open Trip Planner (OTP).
To perform a multimodal logistic system I have to integrate OSM with sea routes.
Specialists of ship simulation can represent sea routes using Route Exchange using RTZ-standard format.

Considering that OSM can be integrated with transit agency’s General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS), how can I convert back and forth sea routes from RTZ to GTFS?

I still don't find any tag for RTZ- they told me that it is a quite new format

Comment: This seems to be the [first post on the site that mentions RTZ](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=rtz) and we usually only create tags when there are multiple questions for which they would be useful.